# Finding the Max Value of the last row of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, max, repeat

I'm trying to find the `maximum value` of the `last column` and i need to print it out.  I tried using the Double.max(); method but it doesn't work for the specific array and I wanted to create an array for the 13th column but it won't let me.

```
 import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class LabMidterm3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] myArray =new double [4][13];
    double row = myArray.length;
    double column = myArray[0].length;

    for (int i=0; i<row;i++){

        int sum =0;

        for(int j=0; j<column;j++){

        double random = (int)(Math.random()*7.0);
        myArray[i][j] = random;
        sum+=myArray[i][j];
        System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + ", ");
        double max = Array.getDouble(myArray, 13);
        if(j==13){
        System.out.print("The max value is: " + max);
        }

        }
        double rowAverage= sum/column;
        if(i==1){
            System.out.println();
        System.out.print("The average is: " +rowAverage);
        System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();

        }

}
```

Comment: You're posting a requirement and code, but no question. Please fix this.

Comment: For example, tell us what problems you're having with the code you've posted, what it's trying to do, what it actually does, what specifically confuses you,... something, anything to allow us to understand what problem **you** are having.

Comment: sorry about that, i edited it. I tried using the method Double.max(); to find the maximum value but since it's an array, i tried using the MyArray as the array then the 13th index but that gave me an error.

Comment: Where do you try to use `Double.max(...)`? Maybe I'm not looking carefully, but 1) I don't see the attempt, or 2) the actual error message, in your post above.

Comment: @Paula you say gave an error but again you failed to mention what error does it gave.

Comment: deeply sorry. I didn't realize i failed to include the double.max in this one. the error is a java.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: I edited the code and included the double.max where i originally placed it.

Comment: Please format your code better so that it is easily readable. Formatting, especially proper indentations, serves a purpose to allow anyone to easily see what block a code belongs to. Since your code is somewhat randomly indented, you make it very difficult for us to understand it. I formatted your last code post, but I am going to leave it to you to put in the effort to format this code. Please help us help you by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calculating (and storing) `double` values, don't cast the `random` to an `int`. Next, initialize `max` to some non-present value guaranteed to be smaller than any value present (like -∞). Then use [`Math.max(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-) to update it while you iterate the row. And you can use [`Arrays.toString(double[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-double:A-) to print your row. Finally, print the average and max after you populate the array. Something like

```
double sum = 0;
double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
    myArray[i][j] = Math.random() * 7.0;
    max = Math.max(max, myArray[i][j]);
    sum += myArray[i][j];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray[i]));
double rowAverage = sum / column;
if (i == 1) {
    System.out.println("The average is: " + rowAverage);
    System.out.println("The max is: " + max);
}
```

Comment: ooohhhh okay, that makes more sense when you explain it that way. so i can use max inside the method Math.max()?

Comment: @Paula `Math.max` allows you to compare two values and returns the larger (there is also `Math.min`).